# Table Spacing Inconsistant

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap, if I put this in a table cell then it formats perfectly:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

In this snapshot `http://gyazo.com/3739de4ebfd4f3a4345739be9893e2cd` it is formated correctly.
However when I use a form it puts a bunch of spacing on the bottom and expands the table row:

```
<form name="deactivate" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value=<?php echo '"' . $row['name'] . '"'; ?>>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

In this snapshot `http://gyazo.com/361987a3601741f02359e5cf78f70562` you can see the spacing between rows, not like above.

Html output for that cell ass requested:

```
         <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <form name="deactivate" action=/controlpanel/admin/manageusers/index.php method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="userID" value=1>
              <input type="hidden" name="name" value="someValue">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
              </button>
            </form>
          </td>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you mean when you put a form inside a table?  Or when you put the button inside a form?  I've tried all variations and not understanding: http://jsbin.com/tow/1/edit

Comment: Ok I have a cell in a table with the code above, the first sample of code is perfect, the second sample causes the row to expand, it is like the hidden inputs arn't hidden

Comment: Any particular browser?  As per my jsbin, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you using a CSS table or a actual HTML table? There IS a difference.

Comment: Is this what you are doing? http://jsfiddle.net/Z4uT2/

Comment: Added comments to explain the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4uT2/3/

Comment: simply an html table, on chrome I have the issue and on firefox, I am not sure about others.  I am putting snapshots of the result after both codes.

Comment: @LagMaster Can we see the complete outputted code including the table?  It's not like the hidden inputs aren't hidden, as they are above the button, not below.

Comment: Good point on the hidden inputs, what you requested has been updated in the original post, do you need more than I have just shown?  I would have to edit a lot of the table info as it has personal information, however I will supply if needed.  It would have to be tomowrow however

Comment: @LagMaster I can't reproduce it.  Here's your code working fine: http://jsbin.com/tow/3/edit.  Unless of course there's something else in the table that could be making it happen

Comment: You probably have some additional CSS applied to your form.